# Woher kommt das Wort "Purzelbaum"?

Tags: etymology

Woher kommt das Wort "Purzelbaum"? Das Wort beschreibt das Kopfüberrollen am Boden, das Kinder oft und gerne tun.

Comment: Welcome to [german.se]! Sorry, what exactly is your question here? Are you asking for the meaning or the origin (ethymology). Also where have you been looking already? What problems do you have? The more information you provide the better answers you will get.

Comment: Der Satz war keine Frage, und bekommt dann, wie im Englischen auch, kein Fragezeichen. Vom Sinn drängt sich ein 'und' zwischen oft und gerne auf. Im Deutschen verbinden wir Wörter gerne zu neuen Wörtern, so dass man eher fragt "Kopfüberrollen" oder "das Rollen, kopfüber am Boden".

Answer (score 11):

Das Wort *Purzelbaum*:

> **Das Wort Purzelbaum ist eine Zusammensetzung, die eigentlich „Sturz und Aufbäumen“ bedeutet. Der erste Teil ist von purzeln abgeleitet,
>   der zweite von sich bäumen (heute eher „sich aufbäumen“)**

[**Quelle**](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Purzelbaum)

Die erste schriftliche Erwähnung war **1571** in **Detlev Arens**: *Von Bäumen und Sträuchern: Fünfzig einheimische Gehölze in lebendigen Porträts*. ([Nach Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purzelbaum))

Hier ist ein [Querverweis für das Buch](http://books.google.de/books/about/Von_B%C3%A4umen_und_Str%C3%A4uchern.html?id=V9kwAwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y).